# Using ArrayAdapter for ListView giving errors

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to add strings into a `ListView`, which gets called inside another `ListView` (changing the ContentView inside the `OnItemClickListener` )

Here's the code:

```
 lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(lv1.getItemAtPosition(pos).equals(cat[0]))                                                       
        {                                                                                                           
            setContentView(R.layout.browse_engineering);
            final ListView engList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.eng_list);
            engList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,eng_build));


        }                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    }
 });
```

And this is the error I get:

[image: Error image.]

Comment: The `ArrayAdapter` constructor wants a Context as the first argument; Activities are Contexts.  Since you're instantiating it inside an `OnItemClickListener`, the `this` keyword does not refer to the Activity.  That needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this

```
engList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,eng_build));
```

By this,

```
engList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(yourActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,eng_build));
```

**As onItemClickListners are not contexts**.